# Screen Brightness, GUI Crash, Sleep/Hibernate Resume, Mouse Pointer Problems with Lenovo IdeaPad Y500

Tags: 13.10, suspend, lenovo, hibernate, ideapad

I thought it'd be better to put all my current problems in a single thread.

I've searched for almost 3 days trying to fix my issues. I failed.

1. I can't change the screen brightness, the bar changes, but the brightness does not. The screen can however dim when inactive for a few minutes.
2. The GUI crashes sometimes when I drag Chromium to the top. I can fix it by going into ttyX and restarting lightdm, but this kills all my windows and work!
3. I can't resume from sleep/hibernate: it just shows a black screen on restart and does nothing. (I also get a thaw error -19 when going into hibernation)
4. The mouse pointer speed can also not be slided, I have to run a script myself. If I go into tty and come back, the mouse is slow again.

#### 3 is my largest concern: It's a laptop and I sometimes have to carry it around for 3 min and then continue work.,

- Ubuntu 13.10 - Lenovo Y500 - i7 (3rd gen, 3630QM) GT650M SLI

Comment: This is probably an issue with your graphics drivers. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114047/nvidia-geforce-gt630m-gt640m-gt650m-graphics-card-support) post, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433) post and the "Additional Drivers" tab in the application "Software and Updates". [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270622/what-driver-should-i-choose-for-my-graphics-card/270681#270681) might also we worth a read.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope most issues will be resolved by following these threads. I apologize for not being able to find them and cluttering the forum.